# How to clean up Vue 3 router keep getting next() called multiple times

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I'm currently working on the router of my web app.
Whenever I use next to go to a certain part it says I've called next() multiple times and that it will fail in production. Does anyone have any tips and tricks how to keep the code cleaner my current solution looks like a mess and it throws some errors which I don't really understand why.

My first attempt

```
  const store = useUserStore()
  if(to.meta.requiresAuth)
  {
    try
    {
      const response = await axios.post('/api/authCheck', {}, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${store.user.authToken}`
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        const userType = response.data.user_type
        if(userType === 'User')
        {
          next('/dash/home')
        }
        else if(userType === 'Teacher')
        {
          next('/dash/teacher')
        }
        else if(userType === 'Admin')
        {
          next('/dash/admin')
        }
      })
    }
    catch(error)
    {
      store.user.username = ""
      store.user.email = ""
      store.user.id = ""
      store.user.isUserLoggedin = false
      store.user.authToken = false
      next('/auth/login')
    }
  }
  if(to.meta.teacher)
  {
    try
    {
      const response = await axios.post('/api/authCheck', {}, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${store.user.authToken}`
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        const checkTeacher = response.data.user_type
        if(checkTeacher === "Teacher")
        {
          next()
        }
        else
        {
          next('/auth/login')
        }
      })
    }
    catch(error)
    {
      store.user.username = ""
      store.user.email = ""
      store.user.id = ""
      store.user.isUserLoggedin = false
      store.user.authToken = false
      next('/auth/login')
    }
  }
  if(to.meta.admin)
  {
    try
    {
      const response = await axios.post('/api/authCheck', {}, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${store.user.authToken}`
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        const checkAdmin = response.data.user_type
        if(checkAdmin === "Admin")
        {
          next()
        }
        else
        {
          next('/auth/login')
        }
      })
    }
    catch(error)
    {
      store.user.username = ""
      store.user.email = ""
      store.user.id = ""
      store.user.isUserLoggedin = false
      store.user.authToken = false
      next('/auth/login')
    }
  }
  else 
  {
    next()
```

Second attempt, I send the user type in the response from the server in three different parts

```
User
Teacher
Admin
```

Depending on the type I want to take them to a different dashboard.

```
  const store = useUserStore()
  if(to.meta.requiresAuth || to.meta.requiresTeacher || to.meta.requiresAdmin)
  {
    try
    {
      const userType = await axios.post('/api/authCheck', {}, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${store.user.authToken}`
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        const accountType = response.data.user_type
        console.log(accountType)
        next()
      })
    }
    catch(error)
    {
      store.user.username = ""
      store.user.email = ""
      store.user.id = ""
      store.user.isUserLoggedin = false
      store.user.authToken = false
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

Third attempt

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  const store = useUserStore()
  if(to.meta.requiresAuth || to.meta.requiresTeacher || to.meta.requiresAdmin)
  {
    try
    {
      const userType = await axios.post('/api/authCheck', {}, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${store.user.authToken}`
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        const accountType = response.data.user_type
        store.user.authenticated = accountType
        return next()
      })
    }
    catch(error)
    {
      store.user.username = ""
      store.user.email = ""
      store.user.id = ""
      store.user.isUserLoggedin = false
      store.user.authToken = false
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
  if(store.user.authenticated === "User")
  {
    return next('/dash/home')
  }
  if(store.user.authenticated === "Teacher")
  {
    return next('/dash/teacher')
  }
  if(store.user.authenticated === "Admin")
  {
    return next('/dash/admin')
  }
  else return next()
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if I don't see overlapping condition that might call it more than once, you should use `return next()` when calling it, this way, you are sure it is only called once.

What's happening is that the code keeps getting executed even after you used next.

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#optional-third-argument-next

Comment: Hmm, even if I put ```return next()``` It still says I get it's called multiple times.

Comment: I put ```else``` before ```return next()``` which seems to have fixed the error

Comment: I've added my third attempt but it seems when I start to add different routes it keeps throwing the error..